# No sound on video demo with Adobe Captivate 2017

Tags: adobe-captivate

I have recorded a video demo that lasted over 3 hours. Unfortunately, when I saved the .cpvc file, it had no sound.

There were two separate files in the cache folder, the mp4 file and the sound file. It is a .wav file of more than 2Gb in size. Unfortunately, I cannot add the sound file to the file project. Instead, it gives an error message for the sound file.

I also tried adding both files together with Adobe Premier; it also gave me an error message of sound encoding. I have also tried converting the .wav file to any other format with Adobe Soundbooth and Audacity. No possible. Sound file error message.

I can read both files, the video and the .wav file.

Any ideas around this so I do not lose the project?